# What does it mean by a touch point being in a frame for a touchstart event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, dom-events

I was going through W3C specs for touch events for browsers, and found this line under [touchstart](https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#the-touchstart-event) event:

> The target of this event must be an Element. If the touch point is
>   within a frame, the event should be dispatched to an element in the
>   child browsing context of that frame.

can you please help me understand what does it mean by touch point being in a frame?

Comment: do you know what a `frame` is referring to? [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) or (the deprecated) [frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame)

Comment: sorry, no idea.

Comment: so, the links in the comment gave you no idea ... you don't know what a frame or iframe is?

Comment: no, I didn't know them before coming across the links you shared, I am going through them now.